# Need to execute an HTTP GET request to Jasper Server to view list of users. But I get the error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#-4.0, get, httprequest, jasperserver

Jasper server allows you to view the list of users by executing this HTTP GET request-
    http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/users/

when I execute this using the web browser, I get a pop up message "Authentication Required" asking for user name and password.

On entering a valid user name and password, I get the list of users in xml format like this -

```
<users>

<user>

<externallyDefined>false</externallyDefined>

<fullName>John Smith</fullName>

<username>John</username>

</user>

<user>

<externallyDefined>false</externallyDefined>

<fullName>alicia</fullName>

<username>alicia</username>

</user>

</users>
```

I want to execute this HTTP GET request from C#. But when I do I get this error - "Server responded with error - (401) Unauthorised request"

Here's my C# code -

```
public void getUsers()
{
var query = new Uri(string.Concat("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/users/"));
var request = WebRequest.Create(query);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("jasper", "jasper");
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "urlencoded";
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hmm that looks like it should work to me, try capturing the requests in fiddler and making sure the headers are identical between your browser and the C# app, http://www.telerik.com/fiddler - then at least you will know whether its a problem with your code or with the HTTP, but your code looks like it should work to me I done something very similar

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Rest based services uses the SOAP based Basic Http Authentication. You can try something like below to enforce the basic authentication from C# web request.

```
public void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest request, String userName, String userPassword)
{
    string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
    authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
}
```

Usage:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/users");
SetBasicAuthHeader(request, "jasper", "jasper");

var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I tried this out but got this error - "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."